# How to use static files with gae-archetype-objectify-jsp

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, maven-archetype

I am writing my first Google App Engine project, in Java, without GWT. I started off by using the gae-archetype-objectify-jsp archetype to get the skeleton structure of the project, and am using the eclipse plugin to develop and test locally.

Everything is going great (loving objectify in particular) except for one thing: my static files like images and style sheets go missing every time I run the project. I've been putting these under `src/main/webapp/`, but anything I create there automatically gets deleted on build.

Is there something else I am supposed to do with static files?

Cheers,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

It goes in a subfolder under war/

For dealing with static files, you should really see this... https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/staticfiles

It's a little disconcerting that src files are being deleted on build.  I don't think that should be happening.  What do you have your "Default output folder" set to?  (It's found in the Java Build Path --> Source (under eclipse)  Shouldn't it be something like project_name/war/WEB-INF/classes.  Of course it may be your maven system that is doing it and not Eclipse.

Comment: Hi. I read the link but it wasn't very informative. The project layout provided by the archetype doesn't have a war folder, it has a src/main/webapp folder instead, which contains things  you would expect like index.jsp and the WEB-INF folder. So I assume the files are supposed to go there?

Comment: my layout is like:project root -->src, war --> stylesheets, WEB-INF, images etc. so I guess you should have src/main/webapp/stylesheets